# Extjs 4.1.1 How to debug Xtemplete

Tags: extjs4.1

I am using Ext 4.1.1 version.

I want to know How to debug the Xtemplate. i.e. 
e.g.

```
 '<tpl for="outerObject">',
     '<tpl for="innerObject">',
          '<span class="abc">{myValue}</span>',
     '</tpl>',
 '</tpl>',
```

Now I want to know what Value outerObject has, depending upon that want to loop into innerObject, and so on.

Please tell me any way to degug Xtemplate.

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way is to get into the browser's debugger:

```
tpl: [
'<tpl for="outerObject">',
     '{% debugger; %}'
     '<tpl for="innerObject">',
          '<span class="abc">{myValue}</span>',
     '</tpl>',
'</tpl>'
]
```

Answer (score 6):

You can execute arbitrary inline code in XTemplate. Hence, you can call `console.log` in order to print some object variable:

```
'{[console.log(values.outerObject)]}',
```

Comment: @Atul, the only one that I'm aware of.

Comment: ok, Thanks a lot Molecular Man.. It help me to proceed further.

Comment: You can also use `'{[console.log(values.innerObject)]}'` or `'{[console.log(values.myValue)]}'`. The `values` variable contains the data from the current scope, not the data originally supplied to the XTemplate. You can even use `'{[console.log(values)]}'` to see what data you have available in your current scope.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is "old" but, if you have your own template or have anyway to come to the template, you can actually add the debugger; command and chrome will jump into the debugger.

```
    extraRowTpl: [
    '{%',
        'values.view.rowBodyFeature.setupRowData(values.record, values.recordIndex, values);',
        'debugger;', **<!-- WILL STOP HERE**
        'this.nextTpl.applyOut(values, out, parent);',
    '%}',
    '<tr class="' + Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'grid-rowbody-tr {rowBodyCls}">',
        '<td class="' + Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'grid-cell-rowbody' + ' ' + Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'grid-cell ' + Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'grid-td" colspan="{rowBodyColspan}">',
            '<div class="' + Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'grid-rowbody' + ' {rowBodyDivCls}">{rowBody}</div>',
        '</td>',
    '</tr>']
```

Hope I could help!

Greetz